# ACTIVATE POPUP shortcut on foxpro

Tags: menu, foxpro, popupmenu

i have a data from sql server then i what to put in on a button to appear as a menu. i'm using

```
SCAN FOR NVL(pkcustempvenid,0) != 0

    SCATTER MEMVAR FIELDS cevname

        lnBarNo = lnBarNo + 1
        lcTempName = cevname

         DEFINE BAR lnBarNo OF shortcut PROMPT ALLTRIM(cevname)

         On Selection Bar lnBarNo Of shortcut ;
            lnBarNo=Bar()


ENDSCAN 

ACTIVATE POPUP shortcut
```

now how will i know if i select a data, it will determine that i click that data.

[image]

but if i click the selected data, it won't appear just like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
on selection bar lnBarNo of shortcut messagebox(prompt())
```

Comment: WHAT I WANT WAS IF I CLICK MARBEL I WILL GET MARBEL DATA NOT TAGUM